# How do I select the version of the SDK in Windows 8 / Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8

I am running Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8.

As a result, it uses the version 8.0 of the Windows SDK, not version 7.0.

This breaks my build.

Is there a way to select version 7.0 of the SDK instead of Version 8.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows SDK comes with "Windows SDK Configuration Tool" to select current version of SDK from multiple installed, see this thread [How to get the WinSDK Configuration Tool to work](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/5ff23788-bd70-49c6-a694-5b5862f57a02/)

Comment: This sounds like what I would need. Except that I can't find windowssdkver.exe on my machine. Is it deprecated?

Comment: Don't you have this one: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Setup\WindowsSdkVer.exe"? I have it installed with Windows® Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1.

Comment: I don't have this file. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Latest SDK 8.0 might possibly have something changed... So maybe you could install Windows SDK 7.0 side by side and have this tool also installed with it.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Not valid for Visual Studio 2010?